# Terraform_Remote_State Error: This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "vpc_id"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-remote-state

Working with Terraform (TF) in AWS and am stuck with an error when trying to call the vpc_id using terraform_remote_state. We segmented out the different pieces of the network in order to mitigate state slippage. However, it also requires interacting with the statefiles of each individual piece of the infrastructure (ie. a statefile for vpc, sgs, roles, etc.). When I try to grab the vpc_id from the statefile, held within S3 bucket, I get the following error:

```
  on main.tf line 78, in module "vpc_sg":
  78:   vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_id

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"vpc_id".
```

This is my terraform_remote_state call in the main.tf file:

```
  backend = "s3"
  workspace = var.workspace
  config = {
    bucket = "terraform-east"
    key = "terraform-vpc.tfstate"
    region ="us-east-1" 
  }
}
```

This is the call within that same main.tf

```
  // output "sg_id"
  source = "git::https://url_to_sg.git/reference?
  vpc_cidr = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_cidr -- This line also doesn't work.. but same issue.
  *vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_id* -- Here's the troublesome line.
  deployment_name = "*redacted*"
  workspace = var.workspace
  tags = merge(
    local.common_tags,
    map(
      "Name", "vpc_sg-${var.workspace}",
      "module", "vpc_sg"
    )
  )
}
```

And here's the outputs.tf file within the vpc directory:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value       = module.vpc.vpc_id
  description = "The VPC ID"
}

output "vpc_cidr" {
  value       = var.vpc_cidr
  description = "The VPC CIDR block"
}
```

Here's the tf_remote_state declaration:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
    backend = "s3"
    workspace = var.workspace
    config = {
         bucket = "correct bucket (trust me)
         key = "correct key"
         region = us-east-1
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the backend.tf info from the vpc directory:

```
terraform {
    backend "s3" {
        bucket = "terraform-east"
        key = "terraform-vpc.tfstate"
        region ="us-east-1" 
        }
}
```

I've tried with outputs.vpc_id (as above), without outputs (outputs is required after tf 0.12 update), with outputs.vpc_id.value (as the statefile makes it seem like that's the structure), and with outputs[1].value.. It gives different errors, but nonetheless they all fail. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the name of the output block whose value is `module.vpc.vpc_id`?

Comment: whoops. It's output "vpc_id" {

Answer (score 7):

The `terraform_remote_state` data source exports the outputs from the remote state under an attribute called `outputs`, which is itself an object value containing one attribute for each output value.

So, to refer to the `vpc` output value in particular you'd need to write:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.vpc
```

...and then to get the `vpc_id` attribute from that nested `vpc` object:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.vpc.vpc_id
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that. However, it looks like I neglected to show how I declared the data source call.

`data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
    backend = "s3"
    workspace = var.workspace
    config = {
         bucket = "correct bucket (trust me)
         key = "correct key"
         region = us-east-1
    }
}`

Comment: I went ahead and just added the code to the original post.. formatting is messed up in the comment.

Comment: actually is data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id

Comment: This is wrong. Like Diogo said, it's:

`data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id`

Answer (score 3):

The way to reference state values changed in terraform v 0.12. See the reference here:

https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html#remote-state-references

From the guide:

> In previous releases, a reference to a vpc_id output exported by the
> remote state data source might have looked like this:
>
> `data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_id`
>
> This value must now be accessed via the new outputs attribute:
>
> `data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simple. Needed to make sure VPN connection was established. -_- Thanks for viewing though!